# Cloud Function get document length - size

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can I get the size of documents in the 'messages' collection with cloud functions?

```
exports.getMessageSize = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
 const check = db.collection('messageRoom').doc(data['messageRoomId']).collection('messages').get();

 return check.then(messageData => {
    console.log('data length:' + messageData.length);
    return messageData.length;
 }).catch(err => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('error', err);
 });});
```

When I write it this way I get 'undefined'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `messageData` is an instance of [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) that has `size` property to get number of documents returned in snapshot and not `length`.

```
console.log('data length:' + messageData.size); // <-- not .length
```

Firestore now also supports a `COUNT()` function that returns count of documents matching your query instead of fetching data of all documents. That might be better since you are just returning the count. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
exports.getMessageSize = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  return db
    .collection("messageRoom")
    .doc(data["messageRoomId"])
    .collection("messages")
    .count();
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work.

When I use .count() I get INTERNAL error on client side. On the server side, I get this error.

https://i.hizliresim.com/hmg4ayd.png

Comment: @blacklistcpp the function was added recently so do update your SDKs to latest version.

Comment: [v11.2.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_1120_-_17_october_2022) for Admin SDK.